# Why does matlab return -Inf with log2 function?

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

I'm calculating

```
info = log2(double(1/prob))
```

in matlab, but when I try to print the result, it show -Inf

`prob` is a `uint8` variable.

how can it fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you divide `1` by another integer, this will surely result in a zero.. putting this into a logarithm yields the observed -Inf... you will need to convert to floating point prior to the division, e.g.

```
info = log2( 1./double(prob) )
```